# Can you get Spring Boot JUnit tests to use the same server?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I have some Spring Boot JUnit tests that require a somewhat lengthy server start up (I'm loading a complex domain in JPA). I've put them into a test suite, but each test kicks off a new server start up.

Is it possible to set them up in such a way that the server is only started once and each test is loaded onto it and run as if the server were started by the test itself?

Comment: `@BeforeClass` setup method possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the solution here is actually built in to Spring testing. That is, it caches ApplicationContexts for tests, as [described here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management-caching), as long as the various things like properties are the same.

Ironically, I screwed this up by trying to speed up the tests by using test properties to limit what was loaded.