# How to start server once before and stop after all tests?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I want to start a server once before all tests and then shutdown the server after all tests have executed.

In Spring Boot 1.3, I could create a `@Component` with `@PostConstruct` to start a server once before tests were executed and then `@PreDestroy` to stop the server after all tests executed.

After upgrading to Spring Boot 1.5, `@PostConstruct` is called before **every** `@Test` method. `@PreDestroy` is called for **every** `@Test` but only after **all** tests have executed!

What changed and/or how should I be doing it now?

Comment: sounds a bit like your application is being created for each test rather than being cached. Unfortunately it's hard to tell because you haven't posted any of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar question with answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42839765/can-you-get-spring-boot-junit-tests-to-use-the-same-server

Apparently, I was being *smart* while upgrading and changed my `WebEnvironment` to use `RANDOM_PORT`s. This causes the Context Caching to be unique for each test class which in turn causes the `@Component` to be recreated each test.

Thanks